# The differential equation for the ground state of the quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

> For a quantum harmonic oscillator, write down a differential equation
>   for the wave function of the ground state, by directly deriving it
>   from the defining property $a|0\rangle = 0$. Solve such a differential equation
>   (up to normalisation).

Attempt: 
$$ a = \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}} \left( x + \frac{i}{m\omega}p \right) \\
p = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx} \\
\left( x + \frac{\hbar}{ m \omega} \frac{d}{dx} \right) | 0 \rangle = 0$$

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you want to separate $|0>$ from the differential equation.  For simplicity, let's just write the ground state as $\Psi_0$.  Then our equation is

$$
\frac{h}{m\omega} \Psi_0'(x) \;\; =\;\; - x \Psi_0
$$

which is separable since we can write it as

$$
\frac{d\Psi_0}{\Psi_0} \;\; =\;\; -\frac{m\omega}{h} x dx.
$$

Do you see where to go from here?  Once you solve for an explicit function $\Psi(x)$ (with integration constant) you'll need to normalize it by noting that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi_0(x)|^2dx = 1$.  This should be standard since you'll get that $\Psi(x)$ is a well-known function.  One advantage to this problem is that if you have the other ladder operator (the raising operator) $a_+$, you can find all of the eigenstates of the oscillator by successive iteration of this: $\Psi_n(x) = \left (a_+\right )^n \Psi_0(x)$.

Comment: Is this correct ? $ ln \psi_{0} = \frac{-m\omega}{2h}x^{2}$                      $\psi_{0} = ae-{\frac{m \omega}{2h}x^{2}}$

Comment: I would add a constant of integration, but yes your answer is correct otherwise.  Once you solve for $\Psi_0$ you get a Gaussian with unknown scalar coefficient.  Use the normalization requirement to find the coefficient.